# Update javascript every 3 seconds only if its new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap themed ad in a panel. 
I have 3 progress bars that I want to update every 3 seconds. 
I have managed to update them with another pages content which is what I wanted to do. Now they are updating 24/7 and it is pretty annoying when it is flickering every 3 seconds and it stays the same. 
I was just wondering if there was a way to only update if the content from the other page has changed?

EDIT: Is there any way of also making it update better? and not just flicker? Maybe fade in slow.

Here is what I have tried so far....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#nav_bar_top').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#nav_bar_top').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#nav_bar_top').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#nav_bar_top");
        $container.load("http://mywebsite.com/assets/ajax/get_bar.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('http://mywebsite.com/assets/ajax/get_bar.php');
        }, 3000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Using intervals for asynchronous content is normally a bad idea. It is going to flicker when you replace content. Maybe you should only update the screen if the data changed.

Comment: Would increasing that interval to 60 seconds, or 120 seconds be acceptable? Why does it need to be updated so often? Why does it need to be updated at all?

Comment: Consider `cache: true,` ?

Comment: I'm not here to discuss why I'm doing it I am here for help.. I would not like  discuss why i need it updating, but I need it to update so often so the user knows when something has changed.

Comment: @mplungjan what would that do?

Comment: And please don't SHOUT!

Comment: Can include sample response returned from `http://mywebsite.com/assets/ajax/get_bar.php` ?

Comment: It would at least not bother the server to deliver the full data if nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I would not loop ajax, but use the callback to issue a new call.

For example

```
var content = "";
var $container = $("#nav_bar_top");
loadIt();
```

where

```
function loadIt() {
  $.get("http://mywebsite.com/assets/ajax/get_bar.php",function(data) {
    if (content != data) {
      $container.html(data); 
      content=data;
    }
    setTimeout(loadIt,3000);
  });
}
```

To fade in and out try

```
    if (content != data) {
      $container.fadeout("slow",function() {
        content=data;
        $this.html(data); 
        $this.fadein(slow); 
      });
    }
```

Comment: Definitely consider this to at least be better than a setInterval, setInterval will continuously send requests even if the requests are taking longer than the set interval or failing. Using this approach gives you more control and allows you to handle errors appropriately with a little bit more code.

Comment: Don't copy what idea? This is how one should repeat an Ajax call. I have to walk the walk so when I say no loop, then this is what I meant. No vendetta down voting I hope?